# How to dynamically populate files in multiple file input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, multiple-file-upload

I'm using a JavaScript lib [here](https://github.com/promosis/file-upload-with-preview) to select multiple image and save them in database through a form, and when i edit the form i get the images from data and populate like this.

```
<script>
var upload = new FileUploadWithPreview('myUniqueUploadId', {
            showDeleteButtonOnImages: true,
            text: {
                chooseFile: 'Įkelkite nuotrauką',
                browse: 'naršyti',
                selectedCount: 'Pasirinkti failai',
            },
            presetFiles: [
              <?php
              foreach($Workimages as $Workimg){
                echo $website_url.'master_image/'.$Workimg.','
              }
            ],
        })
   </script>
```

The Images are coming as `Blob` and are being populated but when i update the data in database the old images are disregard but the new selected images get uploaded. I also checked `$_FILES['images']`. it don't have my old image files.

I have also tried to used methods `upload.cachedFilesArray.push` and `upload.addFiles()` but i wasn't successful at that. Is there any other way to populate `multiple file input`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this library.

It seems as though you've uncovered a problem with a `Blob` type being accepted by your `PHP` server. This may be something that I just never ran into before, because I feel like I've uploaded `Blob` types in the past to my `PHP` servers - but maybe I'm just imagining things and they've always been `File` types and that's why I never had any issue.

Regardless, to make your situation work in the meantime, I made a simple [codepen](https://codepen.io/johndatserakis/pen/QWwvNjO?editors=1011) that loops over the `upload.cachedFileArray` array and converts each `Blob` (or `File`) into a `File` type, and appends it to a new temp array that's ready for uploading. See the comments in the codepen for more.

At this point, you can just upload the new temp array and you'll be all set. In the future I'll look at making sure all the `presetFiles` are of the type `File` instead of `Blob`.